# How to fix "string" length in c++ for all strings

Tags: c++, string, file

I have used string in several places in my base class. which have further 3 child classes. I want to Fix size of all strings so when i write the objects in file through `ios::binary` mode, size of all records is same and i can easily read and search. or will it keep the size same?

```
class product
{
protected:
    int sku; //Stock keeping unit number
    float price; // price of product
    string name; // name of product
    int availibility; //number of Items available
    string brand; //name of brand otherwise artist name
public:
    product();
    product(int,float,string,int,string);
    ~product();
    void display();
    void set_sku(int);
    void set_price(float);
    void set_name(string);
    void set_availibilty(int);
    void set_brand(string);
    int get_sku();
    float get_price();
    string get_name();
    int get_availibility();
    string get_brand();
};
```

Comment: maybe `std::string::resize()`?

Comment: You know that you have to write every single member for itself?

Comment: _when i write the objects in file through `ios::binary` mode, size of all records is same and i can easily read and search_ You won't be able to do that regardless of the `string` size. `std::string` internally is, mainly, just a pointer to the actual string (among with some extra things), so when you write it, and then read-it, those pointer values become invalid.

Comment: Use `std::array<char,FIXED_SIZE>` then instead of `std::string`. Or even better use a reliable de-/serialization mechanism like `boost::archive` or such.

Comment: In general you cannot use `int` for SKU.  Leading zeros are significant, and letters could appear too.  As for the strings, you'll need to make your own class (probably containing a `std::array<char, N>`).

Comment: Thanks Everyone for your response, as it turns out compiler always reserve a fixed size for std::string either (32 or 64 bit) compiler depended.